# How to calculate Opening and Closing Balance in Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-query-store

I need to Calculate the Opening and closing Balance Transaction. I have Three Tables OB, Purchase, and Usage.  The unique Key of all tables is Product id. I need a stored procedure for blow results. Based on the Product id selected need to calculate the opening and closing balance.

Table Structure:  Below code contains Table and sample data

```
USE [BMC]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TBLProductOB]    Script Date: 08-07-2021 01:20:11 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBLProductOB](
    [Skey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EntryDate] [date] NULL,
    [Productid] [int] NULL,
    [ProductOB] [decimal](12, 3) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TBLProductOB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Skey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase]    Script Date: 08-07-2021 01:20:11 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase](
    [Skey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Entrydate] [date] NULL,
    [Productid] [int] NULL,
    [P_Purchase] [decimal](12, 3) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TBLProductPurchase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Skey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TBLProductUsage]    Script Date: 08-07-2021 01:20:11 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBLProductUsage](
    [Skey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Entrydate] [date] NULL,
    [Productid] [int] NULL,
    [P_Usage] [decimal](12, 3) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TBLProductUsage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Skey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductOB] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductOB] ([Skey], [EntryDate], [Productid], [ProductOB]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2021-04-01' AS Date), 3, CAST(100.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductOB] ([Skey], [EntryDate], [Productid], [ProductOB]) VALUES (6, CAST(N'2021-04-01' AS Date), 1, CAST(10.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductOB] ([Skey], [EntryDate], [Productid], [ProductOB]) VALUES (7, CAST(N'2021-04-01' AS Date), 2, CAST(150.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductOB] OFF
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Purchase]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2021-07-06' AS Date), 3, CAST(100.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Purchase]) VALUES (7, CAST(N'2021-07-01' AS Date), 3, CAST(50.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Purchase]) VALUES (8, CAST(N'2021-07-15' AS Date), 3, CAST(50.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Purchase]) VALUES (9, CAST(N'2021-07-01' AS Date), 1, CAST(1.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Purchase]) VALUES (10, CAST(N'2021-07-03' AS Date), 1, CAST(1.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Purchase]) VALUES (11, CAST(N'2021-07-05' AS Date), 1, CAST(3.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Purchase]) VALUES (12, CAST(N'2021-07-01' AS Date), 2, CAST(10.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Purchase]) VALUES (13, CAST(N'2021-07-02' AS Date), 2, CAST(10.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Purchase]) VALUES (14, CAST(N'2021-07-05' AS Date), 2, CAST(10.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Purchase]) VALUES (15, CAST(N'2021-07-01' AS Date), 5, CAST(10.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductPurchase] OFF
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductUsage] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductUsage] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Usage]) VALUES (7, CAST(N'2021-07-01' AS Date), 3, CAST(10.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductUsage] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Usage]) VALUES (8, CAST(N'2021-07-02' AS Date), 3, CAST(10.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductUsage] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Usage]) VALUES (9, CAST(N'2021-07-08' AS Date), 3, CAST(10.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductUsage] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Usage]) VALUES (10, CAST(N'2021-07-15' AS Date), 3, CAST(30.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductUsage] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Usage]) VALUES (11, CAST(N'2021-07-01' AS Date), 2, CAST(2.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductUsage] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Usage]) VALUES (12, CAST(N'2021-07-02' AS Date), 2, CAST(2.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductUsage] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Usage]) VALUES (13, CAST(N'2021-07-03' AS Date), 2, CAST(2.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductUsage] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Usage]) VALUES (14, CAST(N'2021-07-05' AS Date), 2, CAST(2.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductUsage] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Usage]) VALUES (16, CAST(N'2021-07-01' AS Date), 1, CAST(2.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductUsage] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Usage]) VALUES (17, CAST(N'2021-07-03' AS Date), 1, CAST(3.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductUsage] ([Skey], [Entrydate], [Productid], [P_Usage]) VALUES (18, CAST(N'2021-07-04' AS Date), 2, CAST(2.000 AS Decimal(12, 3)))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TBLProductUsage] OFF
```

Just tried: I don't know how to write a stored procedure for transaction-based. I was simply getting all the table results with the help of union.

```
Declare @1stOpeningBalance decimal(12,3)= (select ProductOB from TBLProductOB where Productid=2)

Select a.Entrydate,a.Productid,Lag(((Sum(a.Ob)+sum(a.Purchase))-sum(a.Usage)),1,@1stOpeningBalance) over (order by Entrydate asc) as Ob, sum(a.Purchase) as Purchase,(Sum(a.Ob)+sum(a.Purchase)) as Total, Sum(a.Usage) as Usage, ((Sum(a.Ob)+sum(a.Purchase))-sum(a.Usage)) as Cb  from
(
select Entrydate,Productid,0 as Ob,Sum(Isnull(P_Purchase,0.000)) as Purchase,0 as Usage from TBLProductPurchase
group by EntryDate,Productid
union all
select Entrydate,Productid,0 as Ob,0 as Purchase,Sum(Isnull(P_Usage,0.000)) as Usage from TBLProductUsage
group by EntryDate,Productid
) as a
where Entrydate between '2021-07-01' and '2021-07-05' and Productid=2 
group by a.EntryDate,a.Productid
```

[image: Above Query Output]

Required Output Result:

[image: Required Output]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @Nandha the datatypes are in varchar. For numeric values it should be int.

Comment: @AmitVerma datatypes no problem. Using cast for conversion. I just need the stored procedure for above output

Comment: `Declare @1stOpeningBalance decimal(12,3)= (select ProductOB from TBLProductOB where Productid=2)` This statement is just nonsense. It is obvious that you can (and likely do in actual data) have multiple rows per product. You allow the engine to assign a value from any matching row. You are fortunate that your sample data does not contain multiple rows for product 2 - that fact would generate an execution error. You need to specify which specific row is to provide the opening balance value.

Comment: And perhaps you have not yet considered what should happen for a date that has no purchase or usage row within your period of interest? Think about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to do this

Make sure you have only one record for the entry date. If you have multiple entries on the same date, you have to use a unique key to order

Assumption: you can calculate the closing balance and only opening balance needed to calcuate  and need a system starting opening balance

```
Create table #temp_TBL(EntryDate date,Purchase decimal(18,2),total decimal(18,2),Usage decimal(18,2), CB decimal(18,2))


Declare @1stOpeningBalance decimal(18,2)=150

    Insert into #temp_TBL (EntryDate,Purchase,total,Usage,CB)
    values
    ('2021-07-01',10,160,2,158),
    ('2021-07-02',10,168,2,166),
    ('2021-07-03',0,166,2,164),
    ('2021-07-04',0,164,2,162),
    ('2021-07-05',10,172,2,170)
    
    select EntryDate
    ,Lag(CB,1,@1stOpeningBalance) over (order by EntryDate ASC) as OB
    ,Purchase,total,Usage,CB from #temp_TBL
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I think LAG function is required.

Comment: This answer is suitable as a tip, but not a full answer. You need to provide a working query for it to be  full answer.

Comment: The above query not working for my requirement. Actually, I have three tables called TBLProductOB, TBLProductPurchase, TBLProductUsage. combine all tables and then need the above result.  Table 1 columns : Entrydate, productid, ob , Table 2 columns : Entrydate, productid, purchase,  Table 3 columns : Entrydate, products, usage

Comment: The product has only one opening ob, multiple row purchase records, multiple row usage records.